# AJAX XMLHttpRequest status is 0

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to fetch data from http://dbpedia.org/resource/Los_Angeles site using AJAX.
However, every time I get status as 0. I am trying in FireFox browser. How to make this work?

My HTML page is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
 </head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dbpediaext.js"></script>
<div id="background">
<div id="divheader"><span id="header1">Welcome to DBpedia Gateway</span><br><br>
</div>
<br><br>
<div id="divform1">
    <form>
        <fieldset>

        <span id="txt2">Please select a City:</span> <br> 
        <select id="city">
            <option value="LosAngeles">Los Angeles</option>
            <option value="NewYork">New York</option>
            <option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        <input id="searchbutton" type="submit" size="30" value="Submit">
        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <div id="displayresult">&nbsp;</div>

</div>  
    </div>
     <br>    
     </body>
     </html>
```

And the javascript code is as follows:

```
 window.onload=init;
  var request = false;

  function init(){
 document.getElementById("searchbutton").onclick=search;
   }

    function search(){
 makeRequest(this.form);
 return false;
    }

    function makeRequest(data) {
    var selectedCity = data.city.value;
    alert(selectedCity);
    var url = "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Los_Angeles";                

if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
request = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {
if (window.ActiveXObject) {
try{
request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
}
     if(request){
 request.open("GET",url,true);
 request.onreadystatechange = callBack;
 request.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
 request.setRequestHeader("Method","GET"+url+"HTTP/1.1");
 request.send(); 

}
else {
alert("Sorry could not create an XMLHttpRequest");
}
    }

    function callBack(){

     alert("call back invoked");
 if(request.readyState == 4){

    alert("ready state is 4");
    alert(request.status);
        if(request.status == 200){
    alert("Response received"); 
    }
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make your client(thru JavaScript) access third party DOMs, unless third party allows such access thru [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/). Your code violates [Same-origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

For urgent work around you could use this legal hack- [JSONP].

Or you could get the data from 'dbpedia.org/resource/Los_Angeles' on your server and send to client.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure url you put in JavaScript is exactly the same where the script is executed from. Eg if you are running server at localhost but having url as 127.0.0.1 you rather get status = 0 than requested content.

As written by Rajdeep you can't access from your script to other domain via XMLHttpRequest.

Basically:

*"Any discussion of browser-based technologies wouldn’t be complete without mentioning security.
The XMLHttpRequest object is subjected to the browser’s security “sandbox.” Any resources
requested by the XMLHttpRequest object must reside within the same domain from which the
calling script originated. This security restriction prevents the XMLHttpRequest object from
requesting resources outside the domain from which the script was originally served.
The strength of this security restriction varies by browser (see Figure 2-5). Internet
Explorer shows an alert stating that a potential security risk exists but gives the user a choice
of whether to continue with the request. Firefox simply stops the request and shows an error
message in the JavaScript console."*